# Margin on a block

Tags: css

I have a block that can be used in two scenarios:

- list of such blocks
- individual block placed among others of different kind

What are the best practices for deciding its margin?

Say the block has class `main` and a precending and a following block are respectively classed `preceding` and `following` for the second scenario.

If I set a margin for `main` and for the second scenario, I need `preceding` and `following` to be touching `main`, then should I set negative margin's on preceding and following?

Or another solution is to set margins using immediate sibling selector `.main+.main` and not for `.main`.

I'm guessing I'm missing some other solutions. May I know what are other possible solutions. Also, what are the best practices here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around this is to determine the margin to be set on your .main class div by chaining it to another class that you add based on circumstance. This way, you can keep all of the shared features for your main div in one place and just differentiate on the margin (or any other style that needs to be different).

**DIV Individual**

```
<div class="main individual">
```

**DIV With others**

```
<div class="main shared">
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
}

.main.individual {
  margin: 5px;
}

.main.shared {
  margin:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally only set bottom margin to the blocks, to avoid the margin collapsing. i.e.

```
.element {
    margin-bottom: 30px; /* or margin: 0 0 30px; */
}
```

I also suggest to set each class per block, and use a shared class if necessary. i.e.

```
<div class="element element-1">...</div>
<div class="element element-2">...</div>
```

You can easily use `.element` for shared styles, use `.element-1` and `.element-2` for anything that is different.